# Windows Jenkins slave issues

Tags: windows, jenkins

I upgraded to the latest version of Jenkins, and now when I try to run a Jenkins build on a Windows slave I get the error: `Unable to find a suitable SSH agent.`

I followed the instructions here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28279

But they no longer work. I'm using Jenkins version 2.33

Comment: Which method do you use to start Jenkins slave on windows? Windows service?

Answer (score 1):

My suggested set up:

Install Jenkins Master as a Windows Service.

**On the Master:**

1. Navigate to Nodes.
2. Create a new node and give it a name like Node.
3. Set Description to "Slave for Deployments to "
4. Set # Executors to 5
5. Set Directory to C:\JenkinsSlave

**On the Slave machine:**

1. Open a browser to Jenkins Master URL
2. Navigate to Nodes > <New Slave Name>
3. Click the Launch button. A new (small) browser window will open.

   *ALTERNATE* - If launch button wants to download slave-agent.jnlp

   a) Save slave-agent.jnlp to c:\temp on slave machine

   b) Ensure Java 1.8_66 is installed and %JAVA_HOME%\bin is in the Path (NOTE: %JAVA_HOME% may not work so you may have to put the full path to Java in the Path)

   c) Open an Administrator Command Prompt and navigate to c:\temp

   d) Type javaws -verbose c:\temp\slave-agent.jnlp

   e) Accept the "Do you want to run" dialogs

   f) When the browser window pops up select "Install as a Windows service" from the file menu

   g) If installation fails due to access rights you will need navigate to C:\JenkinsSlave and type jenkins-slave.exe install
4. Select File > "Install as a windows service"
5. Go to Services > JenkinsSlave and open properties
6. Set Logon details appropriately and restart.

**If "Install as a windows service" fails**

**On the slave machine:**

1. Open an adminstrator Command Prompt
2. Change directory to C:\JenkinsSlave
3. Execute "slave.exe install" (without the quotes)
4. Return to step 5. above.